# Alphabetize javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting desired results, but need to order them alphabetically.  I am unsure what to put in exactly in the code:

```
function showClients(data) {
    var html = '';
    for (var clientId in data) {
        html += '<p>' + clientId;
        html += data[clientId].connected ? ' connected' : ' disconnected';
        html += '</p>';
    }
    if (!html) {
        html += '<p>No clients connected</p>';
    }
    $('#connected_clients').html(html);
}
```

Comment: I think what you're looking for is sorting. Sort the `data` by alphabet order.

Comment: What is `data`, an array or an object? By what do you want to sort, the `clientId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've got the layout of the data structure right, it is a key/value object, which in turn contains objects that have information such as connected.

In that case you can use `Object.keys` to get the keys first, sort those `Object.keys(data).sort()`, and create the html from there. For example:

```
function showClients(data) {
    var html = Object.keys(data).sort().reduce(function(h, clientId){
        return h + '<p>' + clientId
        + (data[clientId].connected ? ' connected' : ' disconnected')
        + '</p>';
    }, '')
        || '<p>No clients connected</p>';

    $('#connected_clients').html(html);
}
```

```js
function showClients(data) {
    var html = Object.keys(data).sort().reduce(function(h, clientId){
     return h + '<p>' + clientId
        + (data[clientId].connected ? ' connected' : ' disconnected')
        + '</p>';
    }, '')
     || '<p>No clients connected</p>';
    
    $('#connected_clients').html(html);
}


showClients({Client3:{connected:true},Client1:{connected:true},Client2:{connected:false}});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=connected_clients></div>
```

Comment: That was it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Call `sort` on the data like `Array.prototype.sort(data)`. If you don't pass a compare function, it will sort the elements alphabetically.

```
function showClients(data) {
    var html = '';
    for (var clientId in Array.prototype.sort.call(data)) {
        html += '<p>' + clientId;
        html += data[clientId].connected ? ' connected' : ' disconnected';
        html += '</p>';
    }
    if (!html) {
        html += '<p>No clients connected</p>';
    }
    $('#connected_clients').html(html);
}
```

Comment: You'd better put Array.prototype.sort(data) before the 'for', i think.

Comment: Why ? It will not call the sort every time

Comment: No, that is *not* how to call `sort`.

Comment: But why so complicated with `call` at all?

Comment: data may be not an array, but array like object. So why I called like that

Comment: I'd like to sort by clientId so that when results are presented (clientId) they are sorted alphabetically.  This doesn't seem to solve that.

Comment: So you can pass a function as the second parameter and sort the way you want

Comment: The data returned in the clientId is "Client 1" or "Client 2" or "Client 3", etc.  Very simple.